# Problem on deploy app to testflight with Xcode 15.3

Tags: flutter, deployment, app-store-connect, testflight, xcode15

I archived the app but it only shows packaged Runner(other item)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYkc5.png)

Here is my Runner
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5qTr.png)

Can anyone help me?

I have researched from many sources but still no success !!!